# Twitterrific doesn't save my last read tweet

Tags: applications, twitter

I'm giving Twitterrfic a test drive. I'm not sure about the issue but it looks to me the Twitterrfic doesn't keep my last read tweet after a relaunch.
I mean Nambu and Twitter official client save my last read tweet, thus I can scroll through all the new tweets. Twitterrific scrolls me to the newest tweet.
I can't read the tweets while I'm offline.

Any way to make Twitterrfic behaves like Nambu or Twitter?

Comment: The first question I like to ask when I see someone trying to fit a square peg into a round hole is "Why don't you try using the round peg?"  In other words, why not just use one of the other clients that, from the information you have provided in your question, you seem to think are better?  (Not trying to be a jerk -- I just like to make sure the obvious and easy solutions have been considered.)

Comment: I'm just trying to use and evaluate new clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible things happening here.

1) You have "Always scroll to top" turned on in Twitterrific's prefs. Head to the settings app to check and make sure it's turned off.

2) You're receiving more tweets than the timeline can hold and so your previous reading position is "off the timeline". When this happens, Twitterrific defaults to the top of the timeline (the most recent tweet).

This is changing in the 4.1.1 update however so that even if you receive more tweets than the timeline holds, it will take you to the bottom instead of the top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess my case is the second. I'm using Twitterrific 4.1

Comment: I tried to update to 4.1.1 but it says 4.1 is the latest version.